# Apply file with diff extension in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've gotten a GitHub file with .diff extension. How to accept it to the my branch?

Comment: What I understood is: You have the <name>.diff file in your remote GITHUB. You want to get the file to your local copy? Is this correct? Else please be specific.

Comment: What problem are you having? I'm reasonably sure that git itself doesn't treat files with a `.diff` extension specially. Does GitHub?

Comment: @VamsiRavi, sorry, I wanted to say apply. I've gotten a file with a .diff extension by email. I need to apply it to my repository..

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out the branch in which you want your .diff extension file you want to check-in.
   $ git checkout branch_name
2. Copy the file to your working copy (local repository).
3. Add the file to Index.
   $ git add . or git add filename
4. Commit the file.
   $ git commit - m "Commit message "
5. Push the file to the remote
   $ git push -u remote branch_name

I hope this will help you.

Comment: To my mind you've answered how to add ANY file(s) to repository, not only file with diff extension, haven't you? But file with diff extension is a file, which consists info, which helps understand to git, how an one commit differents from another commit. So it may be can apply differents from one commit to another commit to do new commit. So I want to apply differents from another commit to my commit to do new commit. I needn't add any file(s) only.